# How to access methods in forms from a test method in a different solution file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, unit-testing, nunit, windows-forms-designer

I have two different projects in two separate solution files. One is a test project containing my unit test methods and other is the main project. I know I need to create an instance of the individual GUI form first in order to access the methods in but not sure how to do this.

Also, I have certain variable values which get initiated only when I run the entire original application. These values are used in many of the methods in the main project. Without them I will just get null values and the test method would just fail. Is there any way to get values for those variables without running the application? I tried to place the logic which fetches the value for those variables in my test method and then call the actual method but this still doesn't work. How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you have run into are quite common for trying to write unit tests for an application that is not well written with regards for testability.

Usually the code you write test for, does not reside in forms or UI classes.
The business logic should be located in separated classes within your main project. The business logic can then be called from your UI and from your unit test too.

So you have to move any business logic to separate classes first.

The next thing you need to do is remove any dependencies from the newly created classes to other classes which prevent you from writing a unit test and replace those dependencies with interfaces.

For instance you can change your application so that every environment variable which you mention in your question, is retrieved by special classes.
If you create interfaces for this classes you can setup a so called `Mock` ( a fake version of your real class) in you unit test which you can configure in the test to behave as desired for the particular test scenario.

**Some general advice:**

- Often refactoring the code to be tested (i.e. making it better testable) takes more time than writing the unit test itself. There are whole books about refactoring so called "legacy" code.
- Refactoring an application for testability often means to de-couple dependencies between concrete classes and to use interfaces instead. In production code you pass your production class for the interface, in a unit test you can create a "mock" class which implements the same interface but behaves in a way like needed in your test
- When writing unit tests, you might consider using a mocking framework like `Moq`. It will save you a lot of time and make the test code smaller. You will find an introduction here: [Unit Testing .NET Application with Moq Framework](http://kakimotonline.com/2011/01/02/unit-testing-net-application-with-moq-framework/)
- Ideally you should design you application from the beginning in a way which has testability in mind. The "TDD" ([test driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)) approach even goes one step further, here you write your tests before you write the actual code, but this approach is not used very often in my experience.